# Struts2: How to pass a values from one action to another action. Or from one JSP to another JSP. Without using session

Tags: struts2

Hi I am building a project using Struts2. However during the development I am facing many issues. The biggest issue is Session management in Struts2. There is very limited information related to this.

I have hunt for the solution to my problem but got only limited information that does not satisfy my needs.

I do not wish to use container's session (Apache Tomcat 7) as it will become an overhead when multiple user would try to use the application.

I have created 2 Action classes and 2 JSPs.
The values entered in JSP1 (Login.jsp and LoginAction.java POJO) should be used in another action (HomeAction.java POJO) and later they should display in subsequent JSPs (Home.jsp).

I am using tiles as well.

I have tried using  tag but I cannot able to set a value to it.

In Struts2,
How could I pass an object on a JSP1/Action to another Action/JSP2 ?

A small Login page example would be appreciated.
e.g. A username entered in a text field should display to another JSP page using 2 different Action classes.

**struts.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" /> 

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types> 

        <action name="login" class="org.myaction.LoginAction" method="validateLoginCredentials">
            <result name="autheticatedUser" type="redirect" >homePage</result>
            <result name="fail" >/jsp/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="homePage" class="org.myaction.HomeAction" method="execute">
            <result name="responseOK" type="tiles" >/tile.NextPage</result>
            <result name="error" type="tiles" >/tile.HomePage</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**LoginAction.java**

```
    public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    //private static final String SUCCESS = "success"; 
    private static final String FAIL = "fail";

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() { return userName; }

    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }

    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

    public String validateLoginCredentials() {

          if(this.userName.equals("admin") 
                      && this.password.equals("allow")) {

         return "autheticatedUser";
              }
        addActionError(getText("error.login"));
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Login</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My question is, 
In Struts2,
How could I pass the **userName** from **Login.jsp/LoginAction.java** to **Home.jsp/HomeAction.java** ?

Note: Storing into session is not preferred option but could use if there is no other way to maintain the user state in Struts2.

A small Login page example would be appreciated.
e.g. A username entered in a text field should display to another JSP page using 2 different Action classes.

**Edited**

Hi thank you! I really appreciate your reply. I presume this would work. There is one more thing I forgot to mention. 
An another class(JavaBean) property is present in LoginAction.java class.

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

   private UserData userData;

   public void setUserData(UserData userData) {
      this.userData = userData;
   }

   public String getUserData() {
      return userData;
   }

}
```

UserData.java

```
public class UserData {
   private String userName;

   public void setUserName(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
   }

   public String getUserName() {
      return userName;
   }
}
```

how can I set the userName property of UserData object which is in
LoginAction.java ?

I've tried this

```
<s:hidden name="userData.userName" value="userName" />
```

but it's not working....

Do you know what mistake I am making here?

Comment: I don't understand your specific issue with using the session--that's precisely what it's for, storing session-specific data. Have you proven you have "too much" session data? Are you neglecting to *remove* session data when it's no longer necessary?

Answer (score 6):

Use `redirectAction` with `param`

```
  <action name="login" class="org.myaction.LoginAction" method="validateLoginCredentials">
      <result name="autheticatedUser" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">homePage</param>
        <param name="userName">${userName}</param>
      </result>
      <result name="fail" >/jsp/Login.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

Also, **don't forget** to add userName getter/setter in `HomeAction` class. Then in your `Home.jsp` you can directly use `<s:property value="userName"/>` (or whatever)

Comment: Hi Anu, Thank you for your help. However I've just edited the my question above. It's not allowing me to add into this comment box. Sorry! don't know how to reply. New to this

Comment: After making these changes I received a Null exception

Comment: Break down your problem. First try with simply `String userName` as you have given initially in your `LoginAction class`. Declare the same variable and its getter/setter in `HomeAction` class. Then try to view that value in your `Home.jsp`.
I didnt understand your edited post. are you trying to submit `userName` from login page into `userData`? Dont you need to declare a `userData` constructor to set the `userName` property?

Comment: Hi I've tried this and given me two different results. '<result name="autheticatedUser" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">homePage</param>
        <param name="userName">${userName}</param>
      </result>'   **here userName has been replaced with UserData object.** and got the exception HomeAction.setUserData(String) ... **NoSuchMethodException** does it mean we can not pass a parameter other than a String???

Comment: I have never tried with objects but i think it should work. Is it working when you pass `userName`?  you are passing `userName` in the `redirectAction`, so struts will look for `setUserName(String userName)` in `HomeAction`.Similarly if you pass userData in the result, it will look for setUserData(userData data) method. Are you sure you have defiend correct getter/setter?

Comment: using this line on the JSP page, has set the value to userData.userName.  `<s:param name="userData.userName">${userName}</s:param>`  This line did the job. But while redirecting this object to another action, it does not get the userData, instead it is looking for `setUserData(String)` setter when it should be `setUserData(UserData)`

Comment: And one more thing I have noticed. the **type** attribute of **result** tag `<result name="autheticatedUser" type="redirectAction">` has different behavior for different type. **redirectAction** , **redirect** , **redirect-action**

Comment: Ok in that case why dont you use `<param name="userName">${userData.userName}</param>` in your result redirection and declare String `userName` and its getter/setter in your HomeAction

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, this would be the last option though. In my project in every JSP page there are text fields where user will enter values into it. **I need to carry values from 1st page to last page.** If I use String, then I will end up writing properties into action class. Meaning if JSP1 has userName in Action1 then for JSP2 and Action2 would have their properties plus userName. In addition for JSP3 and Action3 would have Action2 properties plus Action3 properties... and so on.... till the last page...n/Action...n. **If somehow I could transfer an object over HTTP protocol rather than Str**

Comment: If you need to redirect data for more then two actions, then I think storing it in session is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `conversation plugin` is a good wrapper around session, which can be used to manage the objects life time between actions. (https://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/)

This solution will help a lot when you have some step base jsp pages (more than two steps). The plugin in is annotation base and has necessary jsp tags too